# Local variable values and Address getting retained even after function completes Execution

Tags: c, function, pointers, double-pointer

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int var=100;
        int *ptr=&var;
        fun(&ptr);
        printf("%p",ptr);
        printf("%d\n",*ptr);
}
int fun(int **var)
{
    int j=10;
    *var=&j;
    printf("%p\n",*var);
    printf("%d\n",**var);
}
```

Output:

0x7fff2c96dba4
10
0x7fff2c96dba4
10

How is value getting retained even after function completing execution?
I executed it several times in gcc and in online compiler it gives the same result.
please help me in understanding this...Thanks In advance.

Comment: Returning (one way or another) a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration, j, and accessing said object after it has gone out of scope has [undefined behaviour](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2): "An object is referred to outside of its lifetime (6.2.4).
The value of a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended is used (6.2.4)." So that's 2 counts of UB.

Comment: You also never return a value from your non-void function.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons btw, that is *not* UB but very standard conforming behaviour

Comment: @llija Everila Thank you for your reply.. but the thing which I'm not getting it is it  printing the values even after function completion.will it get stored for some time or is it undefined behaviour (UB)

Comment: In any case, these would be explained in a good C book, read the pages 1 to 483.

Comment: this is `c++`, but the same concepts apply: Bottom line, undefined behavior is undefined, _not_ defined to fail. Just because it "works" this time doesn't mean it always will. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: @Raviteja Undefined Behavior means that anything can happen.  Ranging from the code doing what you wanted it to do, to blowing up the moon (people seem to love hyperbole for expressing the possibilities of Undefined Behavior).  In this case basically there's no guarantee the data will still be there for you to read, but also no guarantee that it won't.  It's simply garbage that happens to hold the value you last set to that location.

Comment: After you return from the function `fun()`, the memory where `j` was stored is still there. It even still _may_ have the value which was stored in `j`. It is considered as [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) to access it after return as the resp. memory of `j` was released (i.e. "declared as free") and might now be unused or otherwise used (for something else).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Well it may be legal in the C standard, I wouldn't consider it VERY standard conforming.  Just as it is standard practice on here to tell people not to cast the result of malloc, I figure it something of this nature would also be worth pointing out.  Unless there's a use-case I am unfamiliar with, I do not believe there is a scenario where it is beneficial to have a non-void function with no return.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP asks to explain UB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is value getting retained even after function completing execution?

*Undefined behavior* (UB).  It might appear to "work", but that is not specified to be so by C.

`fun(&ptr);` runs fine, yet `printf("%p",ptr);` is UB as the value `ptr` is no longer valid.  Many systems will tolerate this UB.

De-referencing `ptr`, with `printf("%d\n",*ptr);` is even worse UB.  More likely to behave badly.  Best not to attempt either of these.

Answer (score 0):

The value isn't being retained the method 'fun'*sets the address pointed to by main variable 'ptr' to the address of fun variable J, essentially copying the address *var=&j , it doesn't mean that it still points to 'j'